# How to fix an error thrown by python stating indices must be integers

Tags: python, json

I am pulling from an API in URL, and keep getting string indices must be integers error code thrown in python. I am wondering how to fix this? (The url is replaced with "url").

```py
import urllib.request
import json
link = "url"
f = urllib.request.urlopen(link)
data = f.read()
print (str(data, 'utf-8'))
weather = json.loads(data)
print('/n')
print(weather["name"]["temp"])
```

Here's a sample of the json data:

```json
{"coord":{"lon":-94.2166,"lat":36.4676},"weather":[{"id":600,"main":"Snow","description":"light snow","icon":"13n"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":262.83,"feels_like":255.36,"temp_min":262.04,"temp_max":263.71,"pressure":1025,"humidity":92},"visibility":10000,"wind":{"speed":6.17,"deg":30},"clouds":{"all":90},"dt":1613195709,"sys":{"type":1,"id":5695,"country":"US","sunrise":1613135272,"sunset":1613174070},"timezone":-21600,"id":0,"name":"Bella Vista","cod":200}
```

Comment: What does the JSON data look like? Please post a [mre] with your code, the JSON input, and the full error message you're getting. The error message suggests that either `weather` or `weather["name"]` is a list and needs a numerical index not a string -- for example, `weather[0]` or `weather["name"][0]`.

Comment: Here's a sample of the json data: {"coord":{"lon":-94.2166,"lat":36.4676},"weather":[{"id":600,"main":"Snow","description":"light snow","icon":"13n"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":262.83,"feels_like":255.36,"temp_min":262.04,"temp_max":263.71,"pressure":1025,"humidity":92},"visibility":10000,"wind":{"speed":6.17,"deg":30},"clouds":{"all":90},"dt":1613195709,"sys":{"type":1,"id":5695,"country":"US","sunrise":1613135272,"sunset":1613174070},"timezone":-21600,"id":0,"name":"Bella Vista","cod":200}

Comment: When I attempt to change the print(weather) section to print(weather[0]) or print(weather["name"][0]) it still throws an error stating the Key error: 0

Answer (score 1):

Here is the data snippet you shared formatted in a way that it makes it easier to see what is going on.  As you can see, while `weather["name"]` is valid, `weather["name"]["temp"]` is not, and that is what is producing the error you are seeing. Instead, `weather["main"]["temp"]` will display the temperature value in that dictionary.

```
weather = {'base': 'stations',
 'clouds': {'all': 90},
 'cod': 200,
 'coord': {'lat': 36.4676, 'lon': -94.2166},
 'dt': 1613195709,
 'id': 0,
 'main': {'feels_like': 255.36,
          'humidity': 92,
          'pressure': 1025,
          'temp': 262.83,
          'temp_max': 263.71,
          'temp_min': 262.04},
 'name': 'Bella Vista',
 'sys': {'country': 'US',
         'id': 5695,
         'sunrise': 1613135272,
         'sunset': 1613174070,
         'type': 1},
 'timezone': -21600,
 'visibility': 10000,
 'weather': [{'description': 'light snow',
              'icon': '13n',
              'id': 600,
              'main': 'Snow'}],
 'wind': {'deg': 30, 'speed': 6.17}}
```

Comment: Omg! Thank you! I finally got it. Have been working on this project for like two hours! Now, I just have to figure out how to make a loop for the specific zip codes to be pulled from the API. The way it was shown keeps throwing an error of "can only concenate string not list to string

Comment: This is without the modifications a minute ago from the json, but below is an example of the code: import urllib.request

zipcode = ["7160","72454","71834","72223","72110"]
for zipcodes in zipcode:
    link = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=72714&appid=e7c3fb6e681c8f7bb59af33f1dc8bbca"+zipcode
    f = urllib.request.urlopen(link)
    data = f.read()
    print (str(data, 'utf-8'))

Comment: FYI - the standard library function I used to "pretty print" your dictionary is `pprint`.  It is in the `pprint` library and is usally imported as `from pprint import pprint`.  It is a simple, but handy debugging tool that can be used in place of `print`.